# parse ebay xml response

Tags: php, xml, ebay-api

I am trying to parse the xml structure of the ebay website after implementing their API. I get null values for "categoryId" element and "currentPrice" elements. Please what am I doing wrong. Find my php code below:

```
<?php

// http get url ***

$url =("http://svcs.sandbox.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=Linkserv-9a06-4300-982e-769819b827e9&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&REST-PAYLOAD&keywords=shirts&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=20&paginationInput.pageNumber=1");

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach ($xml->searchResult->item as $entry){
echo $entry->itemId;
echo $entry->title;
echo $entry->categoryId;
echo $entry->categoryName;
echo $entry->viewItemURL;
echo $entry->location;
echo $entry->currentPrice;

// Process XML file
// Opens a connection to a PostgresSQL server
$connection = pg_connect("dbname=postgres user=postgres password=xxxx");
$query = "INSERT INTO ebay(id, title, catid, category, image, location, price) VALUES ('" . $entry->itemId . "', '" . $entry->title . "', '" . $entry->categoryId . "', '" . $entry->categoryName . "', '" . $entry->viewItemURL . "', '" . $entry->location . "', '" . $entry->currentPrice . "')";

$result = pg_query($query);
pg_close();
}

?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you try:

```
echo $entry->primaryCategory->categoryId
echo $entri->sellingStatus->currentPrice
```

Comment: How to add product in ebay using parse url please help me to fix any code for me .. thank you